# Simple POST request/response method?

Tags: java

Basically, all I want to do is get the text response of a PHP page with some POST variables I define.

So, what is the easiest way of sending some POST data (like "arg1=this&arg2=that") to a URL and handling the response (content, not headers) as a string?

Comment: more details?.using which platform? or language

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm using Eclipse, and Java 7.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: please look below replay. i have paste a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use HttpUrlConnection to send a post request using java. attach your all parameter and in test.php prepare your response and return back to sender.

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.DataOutputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;


        private void sendPost() throws Exception 
        {

                String url = "http://example.com/test.php";
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

                //add reuqest header
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0";);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

                String urlParameters = "para1= xxx & para2=yy";

                // Send post request
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                if(responseCode == HTTP_OK)
                {
                System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
                System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
                System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                //print result
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                    }
               }
```